# async.map error when handling list larger of 2045 items

Tags: node.js

I'm having problems handling a file list with `async.map`. When I pass a list larger than 2045 items, the code give a error. And there is no problem of the actual file because on manual runs and debuging with a few files it runs ok. Maybe its not the best code example that I have, but I'm in learning process

```
var insertInDb = function (err, book_data) {
    count = function(book, cb){ 
        book_db.findOne({identifier:book['identifier']}, function (err, docs) {
            if (docs !== null) {
                cb('Book exists already',null)
            }else{
                book_db.insert(book, function(err){
                    cb(err,book)
                })
            }
        })
    }

    async.map(book_data, count)
};
var epubData = function (epub, nextEpub) {
    var book_data = {};
    epubParser.open(epub, function (err, epub_data) {
        console.log(epub);
        for (var i of epub_data.easy['simpleMeta']) {  // <-- ERROR! TypeError: Cannot read property 'easy' of undefined
            for (var attrname in i) {
                if (attrname.indexOf('dc:') !== -1) {
                    book_data[attrname.split(':')[1]] = i[attrname];
                    book_data['file'] = epub;
                }
            }
        }
        nextEpub(err, book_data)
    })
};

async.map(full_files_path.slice(0, 2045), epubData, insertInDb);
```

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: `async.map()` will start 2045 parsers in parallel. Try using [`mapLimit()`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#mapLimit)

Comment: @ShriramManoharan the error is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'easy' of undefined` as show in a commented line in the code

Comment: @robertklep, thanks!! that solve the problem