# async.<fn>Limit stop after first iteraton loop

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

this question is related with an answer to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40276623/async-map-error-when-handling-list-larger-of-2045-items?noredirect=1#comment67817183_40276623). there @robertklep recommends me to use `mapLimit()` instead of `.map()` because `.map()` can't handle a large series of data, and with that solution all works fine. But now I restructured my code, and now neither of the `.<fn>Limit()` functions run after the first loop iteration. do I missing something here?

```
var proccesBook = function(file, cb) {
    testFile(file, function (epub) {
        if (epub) {
            getEpuData(file, function (data) {
                insertBookInDB(data)
            })
        }else{
            cb(file)
        }
    })
}

async.mapLimit(full_files_path, 10, proccesBook, function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log('Corrupted file', err);
    } else {
        console.log('Processing complete');
    };
}) 
// ---> only runs for the first 10 series data
```

Comment: For your `proccesBook` function - does `insertBookinDB` not require a callback? Also in your `else` branch, `cb` should be called with an error object as the first parameter as `async` follows callback conventions, e.g. `cb(null, file)`.

Comment: @cejast, thanks too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your primary issue is you don't call `cb` in the success branch of `processBook`. Your control flow must guarantee to call the callback exactly once for each worker function invocation.

Other asides:

- You don't seem to need the results, so `eachLimit` is fine

  - Only need `mapLimit` if you need the results of each worker
- You need to follow the standard error-first convention when calling the callback. Don't do `cb(file)` as that will be interpretted as an error and about the remaining processing.

---

```
var proccesBook = function(file, cb) {
    testFile(file, function (epub) {
        if (epub) {
            getEpuData(file, function (data) {
                insertBookInDB(data)
                cb() // This is what you were missing
            })
        }else{
            cb()
        }
    })
}

async.eachlimit(full_files_path, 10, proccesBook, function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log('Corrupted file', err);
    } else {
        console.log('Processing complete');
    };
})
```

Comment: yes!! that solve the problen thanks for that and for the tips ;)